# Which is a more correct way of referring to an amount of time that has passed since something happened?

Tags: time

I was watching a show where a character made the statement,

> It's been years since I've played that game.

I thought that was odd, since I'd have said something like,

> It's been years since I played that game.

Which is more correct?

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are both correct but, naturally, for different purposes.

The first is a shortened form of; "It has been years since I have played that game."

The second means; "It has been years since I played that game."

Depending on whether the speaker wanted to talk about his having played the game in past perfect or merely the past he would use the first or the second.